# Open a new windows and close the current one when button is pressed in Cocoa app

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin.forms

I have created a Cocoa application in Visual Studio 2019 and for UI I work with Xamarin forms in Xcode 9. I want to add another window, so when the button from the first view is pressed the second one displays and this one is closed. Could you please help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mac , there is a **[makeKeyAndOrderFront](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419208-makekeyandorderfront?language=objc)** method used to navigate to another window .

[image]

And **[orderOut](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419660-orderout?language=objc)** method to remove window from current list.

[image]

Therefore , you can have a try with follow code :

```
ButtonClickEvent.Activated += (sender, e) => {
      Console.WriteLine("Button Click");

      NSWindow newWindow = new NSWindow();
      newWindow.Title = "Second Window";
      newWindow.SetFrame(new CGRect(500, 500, 300, 200),true);
      // set be key window and be front
      newWindow.MakeKeyAndOrderFront(null);
      // close current window
      View.Window.OrderOut(Self);
};
```

===============================update===================================

If you mean to fetch `NSViewController` from `NSStoryboard` , you can follow the bellow code :

```
NSStoryboard storyboard = NSStoryboard.FromName("Main" , NSBundle.MainBundle);
NSViewController viewController = stroryboard.InstantiateControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as NSViewController;
PresentViewController(viewController. this); // navigate to next view controller
```

Comment: This is actually working good, I was searching for the storyboard reference by now only because that was the only thing I could find. Is there a way I can initialise newWindow with a .storyboard?

Comment: @DenisaUrcan Hi , `Storyboard` not contains `Window` . If you mean `Controller` , that can be created and fetched from `Storyboard` .

Comment: @DenisaUrcan I have updated answer , you can use `stroryboard.InstantiateControllerWithIdentifier` to get `ViewController` . If answer be helpful , remember to mark or vote up it  .